# Black Screen when using Build in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have been researching for a long time and cant find a solution for this problem, please help.

python code -

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from WWTR import G


class person_1(Screen):
    pass
    def pers(self):
        G.player_1 = person_1
        print(G.player_1)

    
class person_2(Screen):
    pass
    def pers(self):
        G.player_1 = person_2


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass




    
presentation = Builder.load_file("got.kv")

class WWTR(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WWTR().run()
```

Nothing seems wrong there but maybe I am missing something, when I run it using return person_1, it works, but build doesn't seem to want to start.

kivy code -

```
#:kivy 1.0

WindowManager:
boy:
boy_2:


<person_1>:
    name: 'boy'
    person_1: input_1
    FloatLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.size
        Label:
            text: "Who is the first person?"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1}

        TextInput:
            id: input_1
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "top":0.6}


        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.15
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top":0.4}
            text: "Enter"
            on_release: 
                root.pers()
                app.root.current = 'person_2'

<person_2>:
    name: 'boy_2'
    person_2: input_2
    FloatLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: root.size
        Label:
            text: "Who is the second person?"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1}

        TextInput:
            id: input_2
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.06
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.20, "top":0.6}


        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.15
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top":0.4}
            text: "Enter"
            on_release: 
                root.pers()
```

Any help would be well appreciated, it starts a black screen instead of the contents of the kivy file, Ive tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `kv` should start with:

```
WindowManager:
    Person_1:
    Person_2:
```

instead of:

```
WindowManager:
boy:
boy_2:
```

and the class names need to be capitalized everywhere they appear.

From the [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html):

> Keep class names capitalized to avoid syntax errors.